# Scala: Why my function can't print a string parameter?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a function which takes one parameter.

```
def weird(nothing: Unit): Unit = {
  println(nothing)
}

weird("Print me!")
```

When I pass a string to the function, it prints `()`. Why is it so?

And why `Unit` is the same as `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unit value is supplied, "discarding" your string value.

```
scala> ("hi": Unit)
<console>:11: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       ("hi": Unit)
        ^

scala> :replay -Ywarn-value-discard
Replaying: ("hi": Unit)
<console>:11: warning: discarded non-Unit value
       ("hi": Unit)
        ^
<console>:11: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       ("hi": Unit)
        ^
```

See the conversion [in the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions).

It's just a way of adapting your expression to the expected type.

Usually, it looks like:

```
def f: Unit = 42  // add () here
```

Your call is actually

```
weird { "string" ; () }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unit is not the same as String.

[Unit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit) defintion:

> There is only one value of type Unit, (), and it is not represented by
>   any object in the underlying runtime system. A method with return type
>   Unit is analogous to a Java method which is declared void.

So, your function is basically discarding the string that you are passing as a parameter, and it prints the Unit value (), as part of the conversion specification.

**Extra information:**

Check the [signature](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Console$) of `println`:

```
def println(x: Any): Unit
```

> Prints out an object to the default output, followed by a newline
>   character.